# Android mobile "unresponsive script" (PHP/jQuery/ajax)

Tags: php, android, jquery

**Scenario**

I am creating a website that has a calendar of events, these events are being pulled in from a bunch of different areas and being placed into a JSON object. Then, with the returned values I grab the data and create the calendar.

**The problem**

I have tested this on iOS, Firefox, IE8+, Safari, and Chrome and NONE of these browsers or iOS show any errors and work like expected. However, in looking at it on Android I get an "unresponsive script" message. I limited the number of JSON data being returned to only pull in 10 events (which is extremely small) and I still receive the error.

Also, if I click wait several times it will EVENTUALLY load...

Why would  I get an error on Android, but NO WHERE else? If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your android implementation?

Comment: What do you mean my implementation? This is a website... I'm confused with your statement/question...

Comment: Oh sorry. Was under the impression that you developed a mobile-app which uses data provided by the website.

Comment: Sorry, updated the scenario to clarify...